# Page is redirected on link click but not when I open it on new tab

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, browser-cache

Something strange happening ( at least for me ). I have a link which is

```
<a href="https://example.com/profile?code=533"> Name </a>
```

When I click on the link it is opened page

```
https://example.com/member?code=533
```

instead of

```
https://example.com/profile?code=533
```

When I right-click on the link and then Open in a new tab is loading correct URL on the new tab.

I have no idea what is happened. Tried all similar questions here on SO, tried to disable the cache, clear the cache. Checked the `.htaccess` but I don't see something wrong since every other link on the site is working correctly.

This is my `.htaccess`

```
#Https redirection
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# redirect the blank request to the home page ( normally it is index.html )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

# Remove WWW from URL and preserve http or https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

# BEGIN Expires
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"

</ifModule>
# END Expires

# BEGIN Caching
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\\.(ico|map|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch “\\.(map)$”>
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age= 604800, private"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age= 604800, public, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Caching
```

In Developer console in Chrome when I click on the link I see 
`Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently`

What can be the problem?

Note: I don't have access to the server. Just to the site files.

Comment: Maybe, there are redirects in the PHP code?

Comment: I don't see any. Also, if that was a case this should affect `Open link in new tab` but is not.

Comment: First of all, clear your cache and try again. However, looking at your `.htaccess` the only 301 redirect you have is for HTTPs, and this wouldn't cause that. Have you checked your `httpd.conf` ?

Comment: @Joe, I've tried everything that I can try on my browsers. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server and therefore to the `httpd.conf`